# ADODB.Recordset to SQL Server query fails due to spaces

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado

I have a SQL string that is used to open an ADODB.Recordset in MS Access. When I attempt to open the recordset I get this error:

> Error -2147217900 (Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT',
>   'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or
>   'UPDATE'.) in procedure SendAutomaticEmails of Module AutomaticEmails

In the immediate window, I copy the SQL that's being used and I paste it into SQL Server Management Studio. SQL Server doesn't like the query either, red underlining spaces... When I manually go in an delete each space in the SQL and add it back, the query works. When I do the same thing in the Access VBA procedure (to the SQL string) it works.

What's the deal with the spaces!? Do you think it's a file encoding issue? I should note that this Access file is source controlled in TFS so the source files were brought down from TFS (if that matters at all).

This is the string:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Person.PersonID, Person.TypeID, ToStatusID, FromStatusID 
FROM 
StatusTracking, 
Person 
WHERE Person.PersonID = 85432 
AND Person.PersonID = StatusTracking.PersonID 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Hey mehow. Here's the string: SELECT TOP 1 Person.PersonID, Person.TypeID, ToStatusID, FromStatusID
FROM StatusTracking, Person
WHERE Person.PersonID = 85432
AND Person.PersonID = StatusTracking.PersonID
ORDER BY ID DESC

Comment: After doing more investigation and using Notepad++ to do some encoding changes, there does appear to be some phantom characters in there. When I copy the SQL from VBA Editor to Notepad++ and change the encoding to ANSI, a bunch of Â characters show up, pretty much where ever there is a space. As for how they got there, I do not know, but it's something we will be investigating. SELECTÂ TOPÂ 1Â Person.PersonID,Â Person.TypeID,Â ToStatusID,Â FromStatusIDÂ
FROMÂ StatusTracking,Â PersonÂ
WHEREÂ Person.PersonIDÂ =Â 85432 Â
ANDÂ Person.PersonIDÂ =Â StatusTracking.PersonIDÂ
ORDERÂ BYÂ IDÂ DESC

Answer (score 0):

As my comment above indicates, it was an encoding issue w/ the "Â" character.

After doing more investigation and using Notepad++ to do some encoding changes, there does appear to be some phantom characters in there. When I copy the SQL from VBA Editor to Notepad++ and change the encoding to ANSI, a bunch of Â characters show up, pretty much where ever there is a space.

```
SELECTÂ TOPÂ 1Â 
     Person.PersonID
  ,Â Person.TypeID
  ,Â ToStatusID
  ,Â FromStatusIDÂ 
FROMÂ StatusTracking,Â PersonÂ 
WHEREÂ 1 = 1
   ANDÂ Person.PersonIDÂ =Â 85432 Â 
   ANDÂ Person.PersonIDÂ =Â StatusTracking.PersonIDÂ 
ORDERÂ BYÂ IDÂ DESC
```